# How to find rows that contains the exact content that i need in c++

Tags: c++

So i have this mini project for school, it's login and register system.
It is almost complete, except for comparing the data. My idea is, when people register, their  data will be stored in either txt or csv file. Their name will be in odd row and their password will be stored in even rows.
So, when people login, as they enter their name, the program will find the name's row, and then go down a row to compare the real password with the login password. So how do i find the name's row? Thanks a lot.
This is my code so far, i'm new to this coding, so it might looks stupid

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include"sosanh.h"
 include"docdulieu.h"
 using namespace std;

 struct nguoidung
 {
   char tentaikhoan[20], matkhau[16], taikhoankhac[20];
  };
  nguoidung dulieu;
  string line;
 
   int main()
   {
   ifstream input_file(filename);

   if (!input_file.is_open())
   {
    cout << "Could not open the file - '"
        << filename << "'" << endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int luachon;
    char yesorno;
    cout << "1, Dang nhap" << endl << "2, Dang ky" << endl;
    luachon = _getch();
    switch (luachon)
    {
    case 1:
    cout << "Nhap ten tai khoan: " << endl;
    for (int a, a < 20, a++)
    {
        dulieu.tentaikhoan[a] = _getch();
        while (getline(input_file, line))
        {
            
            strcpy(dulieu.taikhoankhac, line.c_str());
            array_equal(const char* dulieu.tentaikhoan, 
         SIZE_OF_ARRAY(dulieu.tentaikhoan), const char* 
         dulieu.taikhoankhac, 
         SIZE_OF_ARRAY(dulieu.taikhoankhac));
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                cout << "Ten nay cua ban chua duoc dang ky, ban 
          co muon dang ky? Y/N" << endl;
                    char yesorno = _getch();
                if (yesorno == y)
                {
                    goto case 2;
                }
                else(yesorno == n)
                {
                    cout << "vui long an enter de quay lai" << 
           endl;
                    goto case 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Nhap mat khau: " << endl;
    for (int b, b < 16, b++)
    {
        dulieu.matkhau[b] = _getch();
    }
    getline()//this is where i need to compare passwords?
    int array_equal(const char* array1, size_t size1, const char* 
   array2, size_t size2);
    if (flag == 0)
    {
        cout << "Sai mat khau" << endl;
        continue;
    }
    else (flag == 1)
    {
        cout << "Chao mung " << dulieu.tentaikhoan << endl;
    }
case 2:
    cout << "Nhap ten tai khoan: " << endl;
    for (int c, c < 20, c++)
    {
        dulieu.tentaikhoan[c] = _getch();
    }
    cout << endl;
    int array_equal(const char* array1, size_t size1, const char* 
    array2, size_t size2);
    if (flag == 0)
    {
        cout << "Ten tai khoan da co nguoi chon" << endl;
        continue;
    }
    else (flag == 1)
    {
        cout << "Nhap mat khau" << endl;
        for (int d, d < 16, d++)
        {
            dulieu.matkhau[d] = _getch();
        }
    }
    cout << "Chao mung " << dulieu.tentaikhoan << endl;
}
}
```

as for array_equal heres the code

```
      int array_equal(const char* array1, size_t size1, const char* 
      array2, size_t size2) {


     int flag = 1;


     assert(array1 != NULL);
     assert(array2 != NULL);
     assert(size1 != 0);
     assert(size2 != 0);


     if (size1 != size2)  return flag = 0;



     for (size_t i = 0; i < size1; ++i) {
      if (array1[i] != array2[i])  return flag = 0;

}
return flag;
 }
```

Comment: Obviously, you would have to read in the file one line at a time until you find the name, then read in the next line for the password. Not that hard with `std::ifstream` and `std::getline()`, for instance. What have you tried so far that is not working for you? Please show the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: The even/odd rows logic might not be the best idea:  if a row gets accidentally deleted or inserted somehow, then every row after that point in the file will be badly misinterpreted.

Comment: Food for thought *You never store the password in a file (or anywhere else)*. When the user registers, you hash the password and then store the hash in the file. When the user logs in, you hash the password given by the user and compare it to the hash stored in the file ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to proceed forward with your implementation, you likely want to use the modulo operator (%).

However, I would recommend using a csv format as you stated:

```
username,password
sally,pass1
bob,passwd2
joe,passwd3
```

Steps to make CSV work:

1. Open the file: fopen()
2. Readline by line: getline()
3. Check if entered username exists within the line. Something like std::string:;substr() would definately do the job
4. If matches, then compare passwd
5. Do w/e needed if username and passwd are correct
6. close file: close()